# How to put process in background in Chef similar to Ctrl + Z from terminal

Tags: linux, bash, chef-infra, background-process, expect

I have an command to start a particular service in which it prompts for the password, after entering password I put it in background using ctrl + z,

Now how can I automate it for set of 50 commands using Chef recipe  or any Other Script.

I can manage to enter the password using expect utility but how to put it in background using script ?

Comment: ctrl+z is nothing but a single character. so i bet you can simulate inputting it by sending the correct character in your expect script. in vim, you can input such a character by `ctrl+v ctrl+z`. didn't try it, but worth trying.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr wrong. ^Z is handled by the terminal (tty) driver. in a script you can use `&` to fork off a program.

Comment: @wildplasser it should be perfectly valid since op is using expect. if you use `&`, the password prompt will be put in the background too.

Comment: @wildplasser i know it will work under gnu screen by passing `-X stuff ^Z` to window. i am just not sure here about how expect will handle this literal.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a process in the background by putting a `&` at the end of the command. So:

```
bash '/bin/something -f myflag &'
```

Comment: it will not work, above command immediately puts a process in background and we don't get prompt to enter the password, what I expect is
 "bash '/bin/something" 
   "  enter password : "
    " press <ctrl +z> "
how to automate this ?